# How can we trust npm modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm, node-modules

I'm using many Node.js modules through npm package manager. Since these modules are not developed by trusted organisations, are they trustworthy?

I don't know whether the npm team is doing any security checks for each module submitted by developers.

Comment: I certainly would not expect much from NPM by way of security. They have proven themselves generally incompetent in this regard time and again. Always verify your own security.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NPM is not doing any checks whatsoever. They are just a registry.
The whole thing is built on the trust in the dev community and sharing.

Most node modules are open source and you can review their code in their repository (usually Github).
So that's the best way to 'trust' them.
Some node modules give you prebuilt native binaries, so that might be riskier in a way, but if it is popular (like *ws* for example) then I see no issue.
You can also check the NPM publisher user, which sometimes is a known company like Oracle.

Comment: There is no enforcement that the npmjs package code, and the repository (rather github or another) actually match. It is often the case that there is a gap between both versions, and theoretically it is possible that the two are completely unrelated. So in the end, it's just a matter of trust.

Comment: All npm dependencies have **full file system and networking access** by default, which is absolute madness. I've made a project using the native macOS sandbox to bring Deno-like permissions to Node.js and package managers: https://github.com/berstend/node-safe

Comment: It only takes 1 hack and a careless upgrade of the 800+ dependencies of a 40m downloads/week package for everyone to get pwnd.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to find the most popular `npm` modules. You can do this by checking the stars on each project.

Some tips:

> Use npm to manage dependencies in your dev environment, but not in your deployment scripts.

Tools like npm are development tools. They’re a convenient way to download and update modules. They’re not deployment tools, have never been deployment tools, and should not be used for deployment!

> Use `npm shrinkwrap` in the development repository and check in the result. This will lock your module versions in place, including sub-dependencies

More details [here](http://www.letscodejavascript.com/v3/blog/2014/03/the_npm_debacle)

Comment: `shrinkwrap` should be enough, you don't need to fork the repo, right?

Comment: Correct you are! Edited the answer

Answer (score 3):

**Update - June 2019**

In npm@6 security check is included.
You could run `npm audit` to recursively analyze your dependency trees to identify specifically what’s insecure

**2016 version**

You could use the `nsp` tool provided by `Node Security Platform`, which helps to audit all the modules from your package.json

```
npm install nsp --global
nsp check
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few programs, available from npm, that can run against your package.json and check for known vulnerabilities.  Not perfect, but a great start.  The one I have used is called [nsp](https://nodesecurity.io/opensource) but there are others.

Answer (score 1):

It is not much secure because these modules are not developed by any organizations like what php/apache have, However it is good technology and you can also use `nsp`  modules to check the security issues in you node modles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! Almost all node modules are open source so you can actually view code snippets running behind module. this might help you to build your trust on package you are willing to use in your application

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't use to much packages:

1) express
2) body & cookie-parser (sometimes I'm lazy to write middleware), 
3) mongoose, 
4) pug, 
5) request, 
6) async, 
7) lodash, 
8) string

all other stuff I write myself and put in "components" folder.

let's say most of people so lazy that do:

```
  const md5 = require('md5');
  let data = 'something';
  data = md5(data);
```

but I do it with `crypto` (it's by default included in all nodejs versions):

```
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  let data = 'something';
  data = crypto
           .createHash('md5')
           .update(data.toString())
           .digest('hex');
```

I keep logic to not to use package:

1) if package is small (I always read package files if it's unknown for me package) 
2) version is not above 1.0.0 (no warranty that will go further)
3) no recent iterations (commits) in repository

btw `nsp check` of my applications says: `(+) No known vulnerabilities found`
 (:

Answer (score 0):

I've made [`node-safe`](https://github.com/berstend/node-safe), which allows you to use the native macOS sandbox when using `node`, `npm` and `yarn`:

```sh
# Allow reading files, but only in the current folder
node --enable-sandbox --allow-read="./**" myscript.js

# Run npm with sandbox (can only write to `./node_modules` by default)
npm --enable-sandbox install got
```

When using the sandboxed package managers rogue dependencies are not able to compromise your system anymore through `postinstall` scripts and other means.

Comment: That's awesome! what a great idea! That wa-aaaait a second... How do we know we can trust YOU!?

Comment: (Nah; I'm just playin', I've actually used node-safe, and can attest to it. Not that any of y'all can trust ME either.)

Answer (score -1):

If you are installing a package that you do not trust, you can avoid this vulnerability by running

`npm install --ignore-scripts`

for more details check [here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/141702881055/package-install-scripts-vulnerability)

Here is an awesome blog which can give you clear picture [blog](http://lollyrock.com/articles/npm-dependency-could-be-dangerous/)